# Change my IP on Firefox without third party use

Tags: firefox, proxy, ip

How can I change my IP address on Mozilla Firefox without using VPN or TOR or any other third party software? My aim is to change my IP address from the correct one. I am using Windows 10. I am currently using TOR for this and don't really want to use any software for it. Is there any way that I could easily change my IP address just by using Mozilla?

Answer (score 4):

Your public IP address is set by your ISP. You have no real control over it except to try powering off your router & waiting. Sometimes you will get a new one after a few minutes powered off, some ISPs will cache them for much longer.
Mine has only changed once in 10 years.

Other than that, you need VPN software.

Your 'personal' internal IP address is set by similar rules, but is controlled by the router you are currently connected to.